# Convert array elements into string without traversing array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array-

```
$array = array("index1"=>"8787",
    "index2"=>909,
    "index3"=>"234234",
    "index4"=>"00-00-0000",
    "index5"=>"false",
    "index6"=>"5432",
    "index7"=>2834,
    "index8"=>42847628
    );
```

Is there a way to convert the non-string elements of the array into string type without actually traversing the array .

The array could be quite big as it is created dynamically and will affect the response time.

I could use the following

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = (gettype($value)=="string")?$value:(string)$value;
}
```

However,is there any better way?

Comment: You can't do this without traversing the array, but you can traverse using `array_walk()` or `array_map()` rather than with a `foreach()` loop.... though where are you creating this array?

Comment: But they *are* strings as of now... besides, why do you want to convert them to strings? You know you can operate most variable types as strings in PHP, right?

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at them.The array actually contains the data from a dynamic form that can have n-number of inputs of n-different types.

Comment: Form data will always be strings.  I think you have a different question.

Comment: If the array is created dynamically, why not cast them to strings when you create it?

Comment: WHY ? Why do you want to do this, Mayur?

Comment: PHP will automatically convert numbers to strings whenever you use them in a context that requires a string. What problem are you trying to solve by converting them ahead of time?

Comment: I get them as a JSON from front-end(read,mobile devices across various platforms).Need to pass them on as strings elements in an array.Front ends can't be changed(release issues).

Comment: @AbraCadaver : is that also true with HTML5 btw? Each $_REQUEST item is EITHER a string or an array ?

Comment: @MayurBuragohain that still doesn't say why you want to cast them to string.

Comment: @nl-x That's the way it must be returned to front-end,So kill the back-end guys(that's me) :(

Comment: @nl-x:  Yes, either a string or an array of strings.  Actually, to HTML the variables `name[]` are just variables and PHP sees them as an array.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain: sergio's answer is what you want for JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can doo this only by traversing. So, in such way using `array_map`:

```
$array = array("index1"=>"8787",
    "index2"=>909,
    "index3"=>"234234",
    "index4"=>"00-00-0000",
    "index5"=>"false",
    "index6"=>"5432",
    "index7"=>2834,
    "index8"=>42847628
    );

$result = array_map('strval',$array );

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. You can also do it from within the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$_value) {
    $_value = strval($_value);
}
```

The `&` is important here. (The `_` is just a convention I use to prevent me from mixing reference and non-reference variables.)